# HTTP POST from Google Cloud Functions Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, http-post

A similar question is already asked, but the suggested answer requires request.post, but "request" is now deprecated. There is no suggested on alternative methods.
[HTTP POST Google Cloud Functions NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55836218/6759305)

Problem:

I've been looking for this for two days. I am simply looking for a bit of example code to send a POST request from a Google Cloud Function. I will pass a small bit of data and an auth token, but can't figure out the correct way to do it.

I will hit the API via HTTPS url and pass along the following parameters:

```
-d arg="1234" (a string)
-d access_token=0809809cx089009xci3 (an access token)
```

There are a million docs on how to trigger a cloud function from a POST, but nothing on how to actually generate the POST from within the cloud function.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries other than "request", for example: [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got), [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), or the default "HTTP" module in the standard node library. Checkout [5 Ways to Make HTTP Requests in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html).

Here is an implementation using "got":

```
const got = require('got');

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams([
  ['arg', '1234'],
  ['access_token', '0809809cx089009xci3'],
]);

got.post('https://example.com', { searchParams });
```

Comment: When testing the function on Google Cloud, I get error Cannot find module 'got'.  How do I install a module in google cloud?

Comment: Could you check if "got" is listed as a dependency in "package.json" in the "functions" directory? You may also read about [Specifying dependencies in Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs).